# Shows in the list of questions who asked

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to enable some feature that shows in the list of questions who asked the question and not the name of who edited?

Example:

This is what appears in the **list of questions**. I edited and my name appears.

[image]

But I would like to show the name of who asked. In this case, `Ajay` should appear.

[image]

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest shows the name of who asked the question by default.

Comment: @J.M. How good! Very simple

Comment: @J.M. I have to stop clicking the link that is in the `Mathematica logo`, because this shows the `Top Questions`. I have to click on the `Questions link`.